# TSQL - CAST AS PERCENT

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, casting, sum

In my select list, I want to return a column that shows the percent of appointments missed.  When a client misses an appointment, the source column contains "0" for duration.  So I would like to sum the instances of "0" and divide by total appointments scheduled.

```
CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN event_client_duration = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)/COUNT(event_key) AS FLOAT)
```

That does not throw an error, but it returns a value of 0 except in the rare case when appointments missed are more than 50% in which case it returns 1.

```
SUM(CASE WHEN event_client_duration = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) -- that works
COUNT(event_key) -- that also works, but together they bonk
```

So, I tried to cast it as a decimal, but this causes an arithmetic overflow.

```
CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN e_cl_dur = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)/COUNT(e_key) AS DECIMAL(2,2))
```

I also tried using percent as a data type.  Any ideas?

Comment: If you move the `CAST` around the `COUNT(event_key)` instead of over the whole item, it should work.  The issue you're running into is that you have two Integers being divided, which has the rounding done before you get to cast.  By casting the divisor to a float, the division will return a float as well.

Comment: Beauty!  SUM(CASE WHEN e_cl_dur = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)/CAST(COUNT(e_key) AS FLOAT)  Thank you Adam!

Comment: [I'd use DECIMAL rather than FLOAT if I were you](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/khen1234/archive/2005/05/13/417153.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

```
SUM(CASE event_client_duration WHEN 0 THEN 1.0 ELSE 0.0 END) / COUNT(event_key)
```